# Opening word 2007 from vb 6

Tags: windows, vb6, ms-word

I have an legacy project that I am trying to debug on windows server 2003.
1) I cannot get the application to open word 2007 (installed on that machine)
2) I know that the application does open on other computers as it is written - those machines are running xp or windows terminal server,
3) The application is opened with the standard
declaration

```
Private wdApplication           As Word.Application
```

and code

```
  Set wdApplication = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  If wdApplication Is Nothing Then Set wdApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
      If wdApplication Is Nothing Then
         Kill sFileName
  End If
  ' other code
   end if
```

any ideas as to what the windows server doesnt have set that I need to set
thank you
I tried the methods suggested and it was not successful
I went looking through my code library I inherited and I found an application that does run word correctly, it was setup by a different person (apparently)
it uses a class to connect to word that has these functions

```
Option Explicit
Private bIsNewApp As Boolean
Private sErrorStr As String
Private oWordApp As Object
Private ys As YouthSoft

Public Sub MakeVisible()
  oWordApp.Visible = True
  oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Select
  oWordApp.Selection.GoTo 1, 1
End Sub
Public Sub StartWord()

  'Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  If oWordApp Is Nothing Then
    Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    If oWordApp Is Nothing Then
      sErrorStr = "Microsoft Word could not be located or started. OLE Automation Error"
    Else
      bIsNewApp = True
    End If
  Else
    bIsNewApp = False
  End If

End Sub
```

Is there some difference between this and the other code that I should be seeing
I went through the references and components for both projects and they were the same in this functional area

Comment: Try late-bound method calls with this change in the declaration: `Private wdApplication As Object`

Answer (score 2):

Add reference to "Microsoft Word {VersionNumber} Object Library".

Try this if it works,

```
Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim ActiveWord As New Word.Document

Set objWord = New Word.Application
Set ActiveWord = objWord.Documents.Add(, , wdNewBlankDocument)
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Activate



With ActiveWord
    .PageSetup.TopMargin = 1 * 72
    .PageSetup.BottomMargin = 1 * 72
    .PageSetup.LeftMargin = 1.25 * 72
    .PageSetup.RightMargin = 1.25 * 72
    .ActiveWindow.Application.Selection.TypeText "Test"
End With

Set objWord = Nothing
Set ActiveWord = Nothing
```

Comment: +1, when you CREATEOBJECT, the word window won't necessarily be visible. The OP doesn't indicate whether there's an error, or if WINWORD.EXE appears in the taskman processes list. If it's in the processes list, it's being loaded invisibly.

Comment: thanks guys, I have what is supposed to be the correct object library (12) and I tried out Nick Binnet's code but it still didnt start it. I went searching through other legacy applications on the server and found one that did open 'code'    If wdApplication Is Nothing Then Set wdApplication = New Word.Application
 'code'

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be that the Word Application instance DID load but is hidden.

Try the following, it always works with me:

```
Dim WD As New Word.Application
WD.Visible = True
'from here Word should open and have no active documents opened
'here is how to open documents
WD.Documents.Open "C:\FileName.doc"
```